# jQuery sliding panels - close one panel when opening another one/How to open one panel only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three sliding panels in my html.
The thing is that panels overlay each other when open.
I would like to get a function that create an event when one panel (eg. #panel1) is open already and the user will click on the other one (#panel2) then the first one (#panel1) will slide out so there can be only one panel open at a time.

Anyone can help me with that??

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><img id="icon_1" src="images/image1.png"></li>
        <li><img id="icon_2" src="images/image2.png"></li>
        <li><img id="icon_3" src="images/image3.png" ></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="panel1"></div>
    <div id="panel2"></div>
    <div id="top_panel"></div>
```

jQuery (#panel1 and #panel2 function taken from http://web.archive.org/web/20150227082803/http://www.jqeasy.com/jquery-slide-panel-plugin):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#panel1').slidePanel({
            triggerName: '#icon_1',
            speed: 'slow'
    });
        $('#panel2').slidePanel({
            triggerName: '#icon_2',
            speed: 'slow'
        });   
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#icon_3").click(function(){
            $("#top_panel").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
```

Comment: have you tried the `clickOutsideToClose: true`?

Comment: Yes, I tried but clickOutsideToClose is closing the panels when you click outside the div panel, that doesn't solve the problem as all the panels can be ope together anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Something in these lines. I would you data-* attributes to provide a relation between the panels and the images. The follow up the logic based on the conditions.

**Javascript**

```
$('#panel1').slidePanel({
    speed: 'slow',
    position: 'static'
});
$('#panel2').slidePanel({
    speed: 'slow',
    position: 'static'
});

$("[id^=icon]").click(function () {
    // Current active panel
    var $currPanel = $('#' + $(this).data('panel'));

    // Slideup all the other panels other than $currPanel
    $('.panel').not($currPanel).slideUp();
    // If $currPanel has no active class only then slide down
    if (!$currPanel.hasClass('current')) {
        $currPanel.slideDown("slow");
    }
    // Add class active to current panel
    $currPanel.addClass('current');
    // Remove class for other panels
    $('.panel').not($currPanel).removeClass('current');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <img id="icon_1" src="images/image1.png" data-panel="panel1">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img id="icon_2" src="images/image2.png" data-panel="panel2">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img id="icon_3" src="images/image3.png" data-panel="top_panel">
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="panel1" class="panel"></div>
<div id="panel2" class="panel"></div>
<div id="top_panel" class="panel"></div>
```

### **[Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FEYGj/)**

Comment: I don't know jQuery very well, just learning now. Do you know how to create the function that I could open only one panel at a time?

Comment: You can use the code above. Which will make sure only 1 panel amongst the 3 will be visible when the image is clicked

Comment: That code is opening the panel and is closing it straight away. The effect that I would like to achieve is that the user can open one panel by clicking on the icon from the menu, when the user will click on the other icon, that will close up the one that was open and it will ope the other one that is assign to the clicked icon.

Comment: @Lajon.. Check updated code and fiddle.. I have removed the triggerName when it is initialized so that we can have more control